# Writing custom filter script on Camunda 7 DMN

Tags: json, rest, camunda, camunda-modeler, dmn

I am creating a DMN file where based on certain ingredient percentages, we need some comment on beverages. I need to use a rest call to request and evaluate the drinks. I will pass all the ingredients in JSON post request.

How would I achieve this? Note that, we also need some null checks, incase there is no ingredient listed here.

In short the pseudocode looks like following:

```
if sugar is present in Cola:
 return ingredient.sugar
else
 return 0
```

How would I write custom code/function on cell block?

I am sharing the screenshot of the current state (without null check) [DMN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toBRR.png).
Got error:
{
"type": "RestException",
"message": "Cannot evaluate decision Food:1:1c8bc453-4d53-11ee-b0ae-12d907201e30: Exception while evaluating decision with key 'null'"
}
[Rest call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyzNf.png)

Answer (score 0):

variables is a list. Please take a look at the example request here:
https://docs.camunda.org/rest/camunda-bpm-platform/7.19/#tag/Decision-Definition/operation/evaluateDecisionByKey

Also make sure the keys in the DMN column headers are set and match your variable ids.

If this does not help, please share the DMN (XML).